# 3 letter combination

Tags: permutations, combinations

Please excuse me if this question is too juvenile for this forum. Actually weirdly  I cant figure this out.

I have 3 letters $A, B, C$
I need a formula that gives me all the possible arrangements for this like:
$$
A, B, C\\
AB, BC, CA\\
ABC
$$
Note, the order is not important and I want to exclude the duplicated like $CA$ and $AC$. I need this for $n$ letters.

Sorry again and I am really ashamed to be asking this question here ;)

Comment: You need to do this for $n$ numbers or letters?

Comment: I want to do this for letters

Comment: Then maybe you should edit your question...

Answer (score 2):

Try [$$(1+A)(1+B)(1+C)=1+A+B+C+AB+AC+BC+ABC$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e87122o73op)

and extend it to $n$...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the *number* of all possible "arrangements" per your criteria, then your problem is equivalent to finding the number of non-empty subsets of a set of three elements $\{A, B, C\}$.

This is equivalent to the cardinality of the powerset of the set, minus the empty set, where the powerset of a set $S$, $P(S)$ is the set of all subsets of $S$.

So your answer will $$|P(S)| - 1 = 2^n -1$$